# Filter by nested field

Tags: haskell

My Car type has a subtype 'Part':

```
data Part =
  Part
    { currency :: Text
    , value    :: Float
    }
  deriving (Generic, Show)

data Car =
  Car
    { brand       :: Text
    , engine      :: Part
    }
  deriving (Generic, Show)
```

I am trying to access and fiter a List of cars like so:

```
filterByEnginePrice :: [Car] -> Float -> [Car]
filterByEnginePrice cars threshold =
  Prelude.filter (\car -> engine car <= threshold) cars
```

However, GHC gives me the following error:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Part’ with actual type ‘Float’
```

Which makes sense because I want to filter by `value` and not by `Part`. What would be the syntax to access the `value` field in the filter function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the value by using the `value :: Part -> Float` getter:

```
filterByEnginePrice :: [Car] -> Float -> [Car]
filterByEnginePrice cars threshold = Prelude.filter (\car -> value (engine car) <= threshold) cars
```

but it is more idiomatic to "unpack" the data constructor in the head of the lambda expression:

```
filterByEnginePrice :: [Car] -> Float -> [Car]
filterByEnginePrice cars threshold = Prelude.filter (\Car { engine=Part {value=v} } -> v <= threshold) cars
```

or we can use a point-free expression, as specified by [@oisdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695725/filter-by-nested-field/60695747?noredirect=1#comment107392279_60695747):

```
filterByEnginePrice :: [Car] -> Float -> [Car]
filterByEnginePrice cars threshold = Prelude.filter ((threshold >=) . value . engine) cars
```

Comment: wrt to "idiomatic": in my experience, the `record {field=value}` syntax is pretty rarely used, and even then it's almost always used for record *update* (not access). I think that `filter ((threshold>=) . value . engine)` is *far* more idiomatic.